# How to check if `initialize` is directly defined in a class

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to check if `initialize` is directly defined in a class. Here's some sample command line code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
class Something
  def initialize; end
end

Something.method_defined?(:initialize)
# => false
```

Is there a way to detect if `initialize` is directly defined in a class?

Comment: You could do `Something.private_instance_methods.include? :initialize` but it will pretty much always return true, because it's true for the `Object` class.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to know if there is code in the `initialize` method.

Comment: The intention of your code is not clear. Don't you want the result to be `true` when `initialize` is defined like you did? Irrespective of that, the existing `private_method_defined?` returns `true` anyway, and that does not show your point. (And furthermore, `method_defined?` that you used is even more irrelevant because the inherited `initialize` is private.) You should rather show an example with a class whose `initialize` is not (**directly**) defined as you did, and show that you want `false` for that.

Comment: When you make an edit like the one you just made, you should make clear that it is an edit (e.g., Edit: ....). By not doing so you can render comments and answers non-sensical.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added the word "directly", which was what the OP intended but failed to express, and I removed the definition content. Other than that I did not change the content. My comment applies to the code either before or after the edit.

Comment: Thank you guys for cleaning this up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`initialize` is apparently always private, so you'll need to do this:

```
Something.private_instance_methods(false).include?(:initialize)
```

The `false` argument means ancestors are not searched.

Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-private_instance_methods

Answer (score 2):

You said "defined in", as opposed to "defined on". Consider the following:

```
class A
  module B
    private
    def initialize; end
  end
  include B
end

A.private_instance_methods.include?(:initialize)
  #=> true 
A.private_instance_methods(false) 
  #=> [] 
A.instance_method(:initialize).owner
  #=> A::B
```

If you regard `initialize` to be defined "in `A`" here, I would suggest you answer that by using the last of the three expressions above (though I may be dancing on the head of pin).